# Why the preposition OF in Keats's "... as those whose sobbings were heard [of] none beside the mournful robins"?

Tags: prepositions, passive-voice, poetry

[Written by John Keats in February 1817](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Written_on_A_Blank_Space_at_the_End_of_Chaucer%27s_Tale_of_The_Floure_and_the_Leafe), on the blank space of a leaf at the end of Chaucer's "*[Tale Of The Flowre And The Lefe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Floure_and_the_Leafe)*".

> This pleasant tale is like a little copse:
>   The honeyed lines so freshly interlace,
>   To keep the reader in so sweet a place,
>   So that he here and there full-hearted stops;
>   And oftentimes he feels the dewy drops
>   Come cool and suddenly against his face,
>   And, by the wandering melody, may trace
>   Which way the tender-legged linnet hops.
>   Oh! what a power has white simplicity!
>   What mighty power has this gentle story!
>   I, that do ever feel athirst for glory,
>   Could at this moment be content to lie
>   Meekly upon the grass, as those whose sobbings
>   Were heard **of** none beside the mournful robins.

Shouldn't it be **by**?

> I, that do ever feel athirst for glory,
>   Could at this moment be content to lie
>   Meekly upon the grass, as those whose sobbings
>   Were heard **by** none beside the mournful robins.

The robins heard the sobbings.
The sobbings were heard **by** the robins.

Why is there the preposition **of** then?

Comment: @StoneyB - "I heard of a bank having been robbed". "The robins **heard of** the sobbings" >>> "The sobbings were heard **of by** the robins". So we have an elision of **by**? Or maybe **by** was not necessary for this idiom?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Middle English *of* was the ordinary preposition for indicating the agent of a passive verb or participle. According to [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/oed07arch#page/68/mode/2up), *s.v.* **Of, V.**:

> The regular word for this is now By (sense 33), which began to come in *c* 1400; but *of* prevailed till *c* 1600, and is still in literary use, as a biblical, poetic, or stylistic archaism, or by association with other constructions, e.g. 'on the part of'.

*Of* is still used in this sense with several participial adjectives, such as *terrified*, *frightened*, *born*, *forsaken*; with adjectives characterizing conduct, such *It was kind/stupid/careless/generous **of** you*; in the "subjective genitive" construction, *the action **of** so-and-so*; and designating authors and artists **of** works, *the tragedies **of** Shakespeare*.